# How to write test class for batch apex with in batch apex

Tags: apex

If we have two batch apex like batch apex1 and batch apex2..I have call batch apex2 with in batch apex1 finish method..Can you please tell me how we can write test class, we need two test classes or one test class is enough...??

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, you can't test the chaining behaviour because of limitations of Apex tests, so I suggest you write a test class for each batchable. Or if there is a lot of common data or logic, write test methods for each in one test class.

You can dodge the launch of the second batch in the finish method by checking `Test.isRunningTest()`.